# How to start activity after VideoView end

Tags: java, android

I have Activity , in this activity i have video . After this video i wish run another activity . I try make stupid things in java :) but it doesnt work . Help me pls . My clear java code without my stupid ideas :) I hope you help me :)

```
package com.mem.good;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MemActivity extends Activity {


        @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("/sdcard/memapp/load.mp4");
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 9):

This is what the `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` is for.  Checking if the video is playing won't tell you if the user paused it for some reason before it's finished.

Simply call `setOnCompletionListener()` on your `VideoView` and register a callback.  The callback will be called both in the case where the video completes successfully, and if playback terminates due to an error. So...

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Start a new activity or do whatever else you want here
    }
});
```

You might also check the [VideoView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) for other useful methods.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe create a `Thread` which keeps checking whether `videoView.isPlaying()`. When it returns `False`, you could open up your new `activity`.

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){

        while (videoView.isPlaying() == True)
        {  
            try{
                sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Exception e){};


        }
        Intent h = new Intent(this, new.class); 
        startActivity(h);
    }
};
t.start();
```

But I haven't used `VideoView` before so I don't know what other features it has!

Answer (score 0):

This one has a delay in case the video is still loading and not playing

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread t = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){

                        while (video.isPlaying() == true)
                        {  
                            try{
                                sleep(1000);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){};


                        }
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Main_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                };
                t.start();

            }
        }, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Simply add `mediaplayer.setLooping(true)` if you want to repeat this video. it will **start repeating itself.**

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.setLooping(true);//for repeating the same Video
                    mVideoView.start();
                }
            });
```

Comment: It clearly does not answer the OP's question.