# VideoView variables has wrong values

Tags: android, android-videoview

Does anyone know why me application only returns wrong values when printing out the variables within the VideoView?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.introvideo);
    VideoThread IntroClip = new VideoThread();
    IntroClip.execute(video);
}

private class VideoThread extends AsyncTask<VideoView, Integer, VideoView> {
        @Override
        protected VideoView doInBackground(VideoView... video) {
        video[0].setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro);
            return video[0];
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(VideoView video) {
        video.start();
    }
}
```

If I try to print video.getheight it is always 0, video.IsPlaying is always false and so on.
I have to find out when the video has stopped playing. In other words something like this in the onCreate-method:

```
while(video.IsPlaying())
{



}

 /*Stopped playing, continue...*/
```

But the value is as mentioned always false :-/

Comment: you should answer your question in the answer section and then accept your own answer

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the option for that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
VideoThread IntroClip = new VideoThread();
IntroClip.execute(video);
    video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            setContentView(R.layout.loginmenu);
        }
    });
```

Refer to [How to start activity after VideoView end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808422/how-to-start-activity-after-videoview-end)

Greetings!